# my custom membership provider is no work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i try to make simple custom membership provider to my application.
i try to use login function to login to my application

whats wrong with my code?
why is not redirect to home?/

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string UserName, string UserPassword)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName, UserPassword))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}

public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    if (username == "admin" && password == "1234")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

can someone tell me, which part is wrong??

Comment: Why are you calling `Membership.ValidateUser()` twice? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: my code is working to check username and password.. but cant redirect to index, why?

Comment: I'm not sure you're calling your own ValidateUser function. Leave out the Membership. and try again.

Comment: So `return RedirectToAction("Index");` is called... Is the `Index`action in the same controller and area than the `Login` action? You could check the network traffic (e.g. with Fiddler).

Comment: i try to delete validate user, and my code is look like [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string UserName, string UserPassword)
        {
            if (UserName == "admin" && UserPassword == "1234")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View();
        }     // still not redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {

            XNetEntities db = new XNetEntities();
            int count = db.Users.Count(r => r.UserName == username && r.UserPassword == password);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }



 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(User user)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, user.UserPassword))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

in place of:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: This is what I meant when asking if the `Index` action is within the same controller than the `Login` action...